# Channel Stopped error even the jenkins build is in success

Tags: maven, jenkins, devops

I am running a freestyle maven dependent job, my build is in success but still getting the below error:

> ********ERROR********
> In the middle of job execution getting such warning on console output
> WARNING Could not transfer metadata (http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases): Access denied to: http:
> WARNING Failure to transfer  from
> http:
> **was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata**

In the end getting this message:

> BUILD SUCCESS
> Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
> [JENKINS] Archieving
> channel stopped
> Finished: FAILURE

Any help on this?

Comment: The access to the given resources is limited which looks like you don't have access to... and furthermore it looks like your build does not need the dependency otherwise you would get a compilation error...This means you have defined a repository in your pom or in your parent pom ..

Comment: can you please elaborate the explanation a bit?

Comment: How could I. You haven't posted a pom file nor a setting.xml etc. Does your build work on plain command line? Do you use a repository manager? Is this running within a corporate environment?

Comment: what are the  parameters that  governs "metadata transfer". I mean which attributes and dependencies within pom & settings.xml file can resolve this dependency and this "channel stopped" error. Is it related to jenkins server and snapshot repo connectivity because I am getting connection refused as well.

Comment: Just wanted to know the reasons for "channel stopped" error haven't seen it before.

Comment: You have a problem in your build....I strongly recommend to fix that problem...even if it is only a "WARNING" ...

Comment: I am facing the same `channel stopped` issue but I dont think it is related to that warning. As part of build we have an `execute shell` step where we connect to a SAAS called `whitesource` and I suspect a network latency between our `slave` and this `SAAS API` to be the root cause. Are you connecting to any external app as part of the build?

Comment: "channel stopped" may not be an error, but just an information message. In the example the actual error is "Original error: Could not transfer metadata".